Trying to install following package - pip install snowflake-connector-python but getting error
Getting an error when trying to install: pip install snowflake-connector-python to connect Snowflake. I'm using Python version: 3.12.4. This is the error:
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='files.pythonhosted.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /packages/d5/8f/c493c27751992f3cb34bcf7862fe7669fa905a0c2a4f39ad1f14f8f04920/snowflake_connector_python-3.12.2-cp312-cp312-win_amd64.whl.metadata (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1000)')))


This looks to be a domain restriction related issue from the client where you are trying to run the command.
